# SELECT returns more than one row in sql anywhere

Tags: sql, alias, sql-function, sqlanywhere

I have the code below which refers to two tables, one which is called Angestellten and another one, which is called Gehaltsgruppe. I wanna calculate the total amount of money than an employee with the primary key PersonalID has gotten from a company. The row AmountInEuros has data numeric data type, but I am not really sure if this plays any role.

I run the code in interactive SQL and I get an error saying that SELECT returns more than one row. Does anyone undestand why?

```
   ALTER FUNCTION "dba"."countTotalAmountOfMoney"(@PersonalID int)
     RETURNS int
     AS
     BEGIN
        DECLARE @totalAmountOfMoney int;
        SELECT  @totalAmountOfMoney = s.AmountInEuros * DATEDIFF(month, 
          e.StartDat, '2019-01-16')
        FROM dba.Employees as e
        Inner Join dba.Salarygroup as s
        ON   e.SalaryId = s.SalaryId
        RETURN @totalAmountOfMoney;

     END
```

Comment: Run `SELECT  @totalAmountOfMoney = s.AmountInEuros * DATEDIFF(month, 
          e.StartDat, '2019-01-16')
        FROM dba.Employees as e
        Inner Join dba.Salarygroup as s
        ON   e.SalaryId = s.SalaryId` on a single `e` id. It sounds like you might be getting more than one result from this part. If you are you need to fix your data or do a `SUM` to only return one result per employee. Maybe an employee has been in a previous salary group before and you are missing a "current salary group" flag set to TRUE or something like that.

Comment: The question's code looks just like another question asked by another user.  Are you creating multiple accounts!?